# No alert message after user inputs correct validation (javascript)

Tags: javascript, validation

After the user enters into the field and press "check form" there is suppose to be a popout helper message alerting the user instead it just goes to the next page.

What is wrong in the code that it doesn't show any alert message after the user validates?

I'm trying to make it in such a way that each field gets an alert after validating

```js
function formValidation() {
 var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
  var zip = document.getElementById('zip');
 var state = document.getElementById('state');
  var username = document.getElementById('username');
  var email = document.getElementById('email'); 
 
 if(isAlphabet(firstname, "Please enter only letters for first name")){
  if(isNumeric(zip, "Please enter only a valid zip code")){
   if(madeSelection(state, "Please choose a state")){
    if(lengthRestriction(username, 6, 8)){
     if(emailValidator(email, "Please enter a valid email address.")){
      alert("The following information has been entered: \n"+document.getElementById('firstname').value);
      return true;
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return false;
}

function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
 if(elem.value.length == 0){
  alert(helperMsg);
  elem.focus(); 
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}

function isNumeric(elem, helperMsg){
 var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
 if(elem.value.match(numericExpression)){
  return true;
 }else{
   alert(helperMsg);
   elem.focus();
   return false;
 }
}

function isAlphabet(elem, helperMsg){
 var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
 if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
  return true;
 }else{
   alert(helperMsg);
   elem.focus();
   return false;
 }
}

function isAlphanumeric(elem, helperMsg){
 var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
 if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
  return true;
 }else{
   alert(helperMsg);
   elem.focus();
   return false;
 }
}

function lengthRestriction(elem, min, max){
 var uInput = elem.value;
 if(uInput.length >= min && uInput.length <=max){
  return true;
 }else{
   alert("Please enter between " +min+" and " +max+" characters");
   elem.focus();
   return false;
 }
}


function madeSelection(elem, helperMsg){
 if(elem.value == "Please Choose"){
  alert(helperMsg);
  elem.focus();
  return false;
 }else{
  return true;
 }
}

function emailValidator(elem, helperMsg){
 var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
 if(elem.value.match(emailExp)){
   return true;
 }else{
   alert(helperMsg);
   elem.focus();
   return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit='return formValidator()' action="Lab17b.html" method="get">
First Name: <input type='text' id='firstname' name='first' /><br />
Zip Code: <input type='text' id='zip' name='zip'/><br />
State: <select id='state' name='state'>
  <option>Please Choose</option>
        <option>AL</option>
        <option>TX</option>
        <option>CA</option>
        <option>WI</option>
</select><br />
Username(6-8 characters): <input type='text' id='username' name='username' /><br />
Email: <input type='text' id='email'  name='email'/><br />
<input type='submit' value='Check Form' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given wrong function name in onsubmit method

```
<form onsubmit='return formValidation()' action="Lab17b.html" method="get">
```

Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/knmajLeg/

Comment: Hello, another question: how do I put all the correct validations into the alert when the user clicks "check form" 

"alert("The following information has been entered: \n"+document.getElementById('firstname').value);
      return true;"  

I only have the alert shown for firstname, how do I do the same for the rest? Thank you!

Comment: @dfei Updated fiddle with all details in alert -- https://jsfiddle.net/knmajLeg/1/

Comment: Thank you for the update, I'm planning to add a gender radio button into the form to validate, how do I code it in such a way that it appears along with the other validations in the alert? Eg. user fields in all forms -> doesnt pick gender -> it prevents and alerts the user -> user picks gender ->  alert comes out showing gender with the other validations

Comment: @dfei :Here is the fiddle link with the updated fiddle having gender plus validation : https://jsfiddle.net/pmq0gbx6/ . You can learn form validation from here -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 0):

As RahulB said, your function name was wrong:

```
formValidator vs formValidation
```

By the way, if you're interested, here your code in an other way.

Remember: your code needs to be clean/logical/semantical to debug it without effort.

Every time you repeat a bunch of code, try to make a method.

```js
  function formValidator() {

    // Notice how we can see/understand the logical of
    // the function
 
    let informationAreValid = 
            firstNameIsValid()  && 
            zipIsValid()        && 
            stateIsValid()      &&
            userNameIsValid()   &&
            mailIsValid()
    
    if ( informationAreValid )
    {
   alert("The following information has been entered: \n"+document.getElementById('firstname').value);
    }
    return informationAreValid ;

  }

  // The core of the validation
  //
  // @param {String}     type      Type of validation ('notEmpty', etc.)
  // @param {DOMElement} elem      The field
  // @param {AnyValue}   expected  The value expected, if any
  function isConform(type, elem, expected) {
    let value = elem.value ;
    switch ( type )
    {
      case 'notEmpty':
        return value.length > 0;
      case 'isNumeric':
        return value.match(/^[0-9]+$/);
      case 'isAlphabet':
        return value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/);
      case 'isAlphaNum':
        return value.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/);
      case 'isNotEqual':
        return value != expected ;
      case 'isEqual':
        return value === expected ;
      case 'isMailValid':
        return value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/);
      case 'isBetween':
        value = value.length ;
        return value >= expected[0] && value <= expected[1]
    }
  }

  // The checker
  //
  // We validate the values, send a alert message if information
  // is bad and focus in the field.
  //
  // @return true if value of Dom element with id +idElem+ 
  // match against the +typeValidation+ and the +expected+
  // value if any.
  // Otherwise, display an alert message and return false 
  //
  function check(typeValidation, idElem, expected, errorMsg ){
    let elem = document.getElementById( idElem ) ;
    if ( isConform(typeValidation, elem, expected) ) { return true }
    switch ( typeValidation ) {
    case 'isBetween':
      let [min, max] = expected ;
      errorMsg = eval('`'+errorMsg+'`') ;
    }
    alert(errorMsg);
    elem.focus() ;
    return false ;
  }

  // Check method of every form field
  //
  // Here's is defined the error messages
  
  function firstNameIsValid() {
    let res = check('notEmpty', 'firstname', null, "First name is required") ;
    if ( ! res ) { return false }
    return check('isAlphabet', 'firstname', "Please enter only letters for first name");
  }
  function zipIsValid(){
    return check('isNumeric', 'zip', null, "Please enter only a valid zip code") ;
  }
  function stateIsValid()
  {
    return check('isNotEqual', 'state', "Please Choose", "Please choose a state") ;
  }
  function mailIsValid()
  {
    return check('isMailValid', 'email', null, "Please enter a valid email address") ;
  }
  function userNameIsValid()
  {
    return check('isBetween', 'username', [6, 8], "Please enter between ${min} and ${max} characters") ;
  }
```

```html
<form onsubmit='return formValidator()' action="" method="get">
First Name: <input type='text' id='firstname' name='first' /><br />
Zip Code: <input type='text' id='zip' name='zip'/><br />
State: <select id='state' name='state'>
  <option>Please Choose</option>
        <option>AL</option>
        <option>TX</option>
        <option>CA</option>
        <option>WI</option>
</select><br />
Username(6-8 characters): <input type='text' id='username' name='username' /><br />
Email: <input type='text' id='email'  name='email'/><br />
<input type='submit' value='Check Form' />
</form>
```

Comment: Hello, another question: how do I put all the correct validations into the alert when the user clicks "check form" 

"alert("The following information has been entered: \n"+document.getElementById('firstname').value);
      return true;"  

I only have the alert shown for firstname, how do I do the same for the rest? Thank you!